# A manga about a dude who kills a dog with car and levels up

Tags: story-identification, manga, supernatural

He then gets to pick a job and gets assassin, later ninja. He finds a Shiba outside that he used to feed and gives her the magic stone that he got from the wolf. he then learns that his Shiba can use the skills from the monsters cores that he gives her. He meets a girl that has a gun and the job neet with a gacha system. It is Japanese style and I don't know how many chapters it has

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[The World Is Overflowing with Monster, I’m Taking a Liking to This Life](https://myanimelist.net/manga/118652/Monster_ga_Afureru_Sekai_ni_Natta_node_Suki_ni_Ikitai_to_Omoimasu) (AKA Monster ga Afureru Sekai ni Natta node, Suki ni Ikitai to Omoimasu)*

> On his way home from his office, the main protagonist drove and ran over a big dog. At that moment, he heard the sudden sound of a voice inside his head. ≪The monster has been subjugated, gaining experience points.≫ 「Eh?」 Before anyone knew, the world has changed. Monsters appear, this is a game-like world where levels, skills, and status exist. This is an adventure where the modern world becomes fantasy and where the main protagonist has to strive hard for his survival.
>
> [image]